# Early Stopping not stop in Keras

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying myself with Keras.

I built a model that contain 3 Dense Layers with 1 Masking at the beginning.So I did put the EarlyStopping which monitor the `'val-loss'` But as you can see below, after so many epoch with `val_loss` is the same, the model keep training. I don't know if I declared EarlyStopping wrong.

```
3/3 - 0s - loss: 0.3445 - accuracy: 0.3743 - val_loss: 0.4220 - val_accuracy: 0.3510
Epoch 460/500
3/3 - 0s - loss: 0.3448 - accuracy: 0.3630 - val_loss: 0.4220 - val_accuracy: 0.3510
Epoch 461/500
3/3 - 0s - loss: 0.3445 - accuracy: 0.3681 - val_loss: 0.4220 - val_accuracy: 0.3510
Epoch 462/500
3/3 - 0s - loss: 0.3447 - accuracy: 0.3592 - val_loss: 0.4220 - val_accuracy: 0.3510
Epoch 463/500
3/3 - 0s - loss: 0.3446 - accuracy: 0.3660 - val_loss: 0.4220 - val_accuracy: 0.3510
Epoch 464/500
3/3 - 0s - loss: 0.3445 - accuracy: 0.3653 - val_loss: 0.4220 - val_accuracy: 0.3510
Epoch 465/500
3/3 - 0s - loss: 0.3446 - accuracy: 0.3678 - val_loss: 0.4220 - val_accuracy: 0.3510
Epoch 466/500
3/3 - 0s - loss: 0.3445 - accuracy: 0.3633 - val_loss: 0.4220 - val_accuracy: 0.3510
Epoch 467/500
3/3 - 0s - loss: 0.3446 - accuracy: 0.3614 - val_loss: 0.4220 - val_accuracy: 0.3510
Epoch 468/500
3/3 - 0s - loss: 0.3445 - accuracy: 0.3669 - val_loss: 0.4220 - val_accuracy: 0.3510
Epoch 469/500
3/3 - 0s - loss: 0.3446 - accuracy: 0.3677 - val_loss: 0.4220 - val_accuracy: 0.3510
Epoch 470/500
3/3 - 0s - loss: 0.3446 - accuracy: 0.3609 - val_loss: 0.4220 - val_accuracy: 0.3510
Epoch 471/500
3/3 - 0s - loss: 0.3444 - accuracy: 0.3743 - val_loss: 0.4220 - val_accuracy: 0.3510
Epoch 472/500
3/3 - 0s - loss: 0.3446 - accuracy: 0.3641 - val_loss: 0.4220 - val_accuracy: 0.3510
```

Here is my code for the model :

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Masking(mask_value=0., input_shape=(498, 20)))
model.add(layers.Dense(16,activation ='relu')) 
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(8,activation ='relu')) 
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(3,activation='softmax'))
model.add(layers.Activation('softmax'))
model.summary()

opt = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=2, verbose=2)
history = model.fit(
    x_train, y_train,
    epochs=500, batch_size=32,
    validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
    verbose = 2,
    callbacks=[es]
    )
scores = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=2)
```

Comment: Try mentioning mode=min in `es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=2, verbose=2, mode='min')`

Comment: @AmitVikramSingh I did like you suggest but I still have the same. The model keep training until end of epochs.

Comment: Try adding `min_delta = 1e-2` in EarlyStopping.

Comment: @AmitVikramSingh it actually work. But I don't know why my version of code above not stop? Normally I think it should work.

Comment: May be it's decreasing a bit in each epoch say in order of 1e-5.